# hql query to persist data in table having many to one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

```
@Entity(name="card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    private int id;

    @Transient
    private int slotID;

    @Column(name="macId")
    private String macId;

    private String cardType;

    /* getter and setters */
}

@Entity(name="PhysicalPort")
public class PhysicalPort  {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="cardPort")
    private int cardPort;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cardId")
    private Card cardInfo;

    /* getter and setters */
}
```

In repository class I am using below query to persist data

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(physicalPort);
```

while persisting data i need to add data only in PhysicalPort table with card table id as reference key, but data is added in card table also with a new id.

Comment: How you create/take from database the Card entity? does it have id set? what are your hibernate settings?

Comment: When you add cardInfo to PhysicalPort, I supose you write Card cardInfo = new Card(); so you add a new object

Comment: @JoeTaras ya i m sending a json object consisting card data too..
  {
   "cardPort": "1",
   "interfaceName": "E1",
   "state": "enable",
   "fec": true,
   "systemLoopback": false,
   "rxBytes": 513,
   "rxPackets": 0,
   "rxErrorPackets": 571017851,
   "rxPacketsDrops": 1852797802,
   "txBytes": 1869116517,
   "txPackets": 154804836,
   "txErroPackets": 0,
   "txPacketsDrops": 0,
   "time": "23:56:35",
   "memoryTotal": 4278190080,
   "memoryFree": 4294967295,
   "cpuuser": 996646,
   "cpusys": 104071,
   "cardInfo":
     {
     
      "cardType":"TDM",
      "macId":"12"
     }
  }

Comment: but if i send json object having only physicalport data than in that case in refernce column(cardId) is showing null. what i want is when i add a physical port from gui it should add only in physicalport table with cardid reference.

Comment: i m not sure whether this is hql query problem or data in json object..

Comment: your cardInfo has not id, you have specified only macId and cardType props. So when you try to persist, you create a new card object

Answer (score 0):

You save two cards because your object is passed as new object:

This is your Json:

`{ "cardPort":   "1", "interfaceName":   "E1", "state":  "enable", "fec":    true, "systemLoopback": false, "rxBytes":   513, "rxPackets":   0, "rxErrorPackets": 571017851, "rxPacketsDrops":   1852797802, "txBytes":  1869116517, "txPackets":    154804836, "txErroPackets": 0, "txPacketsDrops":    0, "time":  "23:56:35", "memoryTotal":  4278190080, "memoryFree": 4294967295, "cpuuser":    996646, "cpusys":   104071, "cardInfo": { "cardType":"TDM", "macId":"12" } }`

Your cardInfo proprerty is setted in this way:

`"cardInfo": { "cardType":"TDM", "macId":"12" }`

So, you tell at entity manager, to add a cardInfo without id (id = null) because is not specified.

So, when you try to save PhysicalPort object the behaviour is:

Check the foreign key fields (your cardInfo property), that object hasn't id valued, so that is a new object -> INSERT INTO

Check PhysicalPort object and add a new row in PhysicalPort.

If you want fix your code, when you pass the cardInfo object explicit the value of ID of your row presents in that table, as follow:

`"cardInfo": { "id":"value of your row id", "cardType":"TDM", "macId":"12" }`